# How many electrons are emitted from emitter to base in npn transistor?

Tags: transistors, current, power-electronics

How many electrons are emitted from emitter to base in npn transistor? If base has 100 holes and emitter has 10,000 electrons. How many electrons enter base? 100 or 10,000?

Comment: Is this one of those "How many angels can dance on the head of a pin" kind of questions?

Answer (score 5):

From \$ Q = It \$ where \$ Q \$ is charge, \$ I \$ is current and \$ t \$ is time you can calculate the charge passing a point.

In your case you measure or calculate the base current and use that as the *I* term in the above equation.

Note that you not only omitted current but also forgot to include time in your question. This shows a poor grasp of the subject so it may be time to go back to basic circuits and get your foundations right.

In general you will find that thinking in terms of electrons is not helpful in electronics design. We use voltage, current and power for most design calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Well,  emitter_continuously_ "emits"  electrons when forward biased, an npn transistor (in CE arrangement)  will have its emitter more negative  than its base when forward biased, thus voltage source will cause electrons to move away from emitter.  Also remember that collector is more positive than base.

Now,  we can not comment about exact no.  of electrons unless time and current are known,  but from your question it seems that you're interested in knowing that what happens to a group of say,  10,000 electrons which are currently in emitter.

Under forward bias,  this all 10,000 electrons will move into base,  where they'll recombine with holes,  say 100 holes,  the remaining electrons will cross base-collector junction and reach collector, this will constitute,  collector current Ic in opposite direction to the electrons flow.